# Moving a running AWS instance to a different region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an EC2 Instance (for some reason) with the availability zone of us-east-2c.

My App will only be available to be used in Europe though.

Should I change the availability zone or does it not really matter?

Also in the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axVsX.png), we can see that many other regions have been selected by default. Should I deselect these - for eg. Asia Pacific (Hong Kong) - in order to reduce my AWS monthly cost or is this irrelevant?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Availability Zone seems irrelevant here. It sounds like you might need to move it to a different Region. However without more information about the type of application, any CDN usage, etc. there is no way someone could tell you if it needs to be moved into a European AWS Region, or if keeping it in `us-east-2` will be acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two questions here. I will answer them separately:

1) If you have launched an instance in us-east-2 then it will physically reside in that region (in this case Ohio, USA). You can still access that instance from Europe, however you will see [increased latency](https://www.cloudping.co/) from Europe. It is not possible to simply move an instance to another region. You can either terminate it, launch a new one in the desired region and perform the same installation steps. Or you can create a snapshot of the EBS volume, copy the snapshot over to the desired region and then launch an instance in the desired region from that snapshot.

2) You are only charged for services that you have deployed within a region. So having all the regions enabled will not cost you anything unless you have services deployed in those regions.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer! I will change the region then and run a new instance after terminating the old one. In regards to your 2) point, say my app is only available in Europe, but then someone may travel to Asia for holidays and uses the app there - will that be considered as a deployment in that region meaning additional cost for me? Ideally I wouldn't want my app to be used anywhere outside the EU to keep my server cost low at first - is this possible? Ps. The App is similar to Tinder, its basically a networking app with chat functions etc..

Comment: It does not matter where in the world your server is accessed from, it will not cost you any more than the region that you have it deployed in. Your users may see increased latency if they are in a region far away from the region that your service is deployed in, but it will not cost you any more.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your instance, yes.

It's on the other side of the planet, which means you'll be adding to app's latency. Even if you're using CloudFront, CloudFront doesn't deal with everything. But it sounds like you're not, in which case you should definitely move it.

And, depending on what your app is doing and what data it is recording, there might be a legal requirement to have that data stored in Europe.

Doesn't matter much if a region is enabled or not. That's more of a safety flag, so that you don't use a different region by mistake.